# Validating a RewriteRule line using preg_match_all() function

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to validate a RewriteRule line using preg_match_all(),

Here is the line I am trying to validate to :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /edt.php
```

and this is my  regex pattern so far :

```
RewriteRules\s+[^s]+\s+[^s]+\s+([NC,NE,L,R])?/i
```

The last argument [NC,NE,L,R] is optional in the line.

My complete code with php

```
$x="RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /edt.php ";

if(preg_match_all("/RewriteRules\s+[^s]+\s+[^s]+\s+([NC,NE,L,R])?/i",$x,$m))
{echo "Line is ok";}
else
{echo "There is something wrong with the line";}
```

This is not working, I am getting the "else" part of the code in my output. I believe there is something wrong with the pattern , I have already wasted 20mnts trying to solve it by myself, but I could not find  where exectly the fault is.

Any help is much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot I don't understand about this question, but I will do what I can to try and help you out here.

Let's start with your string:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /edt.php
```

This can be matched a number of ways, but I will just give you a general approach to doing it and show you a couple of potential errors that you have.

It as though you are just matching a pattern like this:

```
RewriteRule SPACE SOMETHING SPACE SOMETHING SPACE OPTIONAL_DATA_WITH BRACKETS
      1       2       3       4       5       6                 7
```

Here is a regular expression that matches this:

```
^RewriteRule  \s+  .*?  \s+  .*?  (?:$|\s+  \[[A-Z,]+\])
     1         2    3    4    5       6           7
```

*I have added in whitespace to my expression simply to make it easier to read.  There should be no actual space characters in this expression.*

1. `^RewriteRule` Simply matching the phrase.  We use the `^` to anchor it to the beginning of the line.
2. `\s+` Requiring at least one space before the next item.  This is already what you are using.
3. `.*?` This is kind of a catch-all that can be refined down to whatever specifics you wish.  But for this purpose, I am just saying to match any character `.`, any number of times `*`, until you hit the next item to match `?`.  In this case, the next item is a whitespace character.
4. `\s+` Requiring at least one space before the next item
5. `.*?` Matching any character, any number of times until the next item.
6. `(?:$|\s+` This may look like a mess, but it's really just matching either the end of the line or a whitespace character.  `(?:` is made up of two parts that just says to start a new group `(`, but don't remember it `?:`.  I am following that with a line ending `$` or `|` a space `\s+`.
7. `\[[A-Z,]+\])` This last bit of the expression is simply matching a literal opening square brace `[`, followed by a character class consisting of letters or a comma `[A-Z,]` and requiring at least one of them to be present `+`.  I'm closing it out with an ending square brace `]` and the closing parenthesis `)` for the "or".

This can be fine-tuned quite a bit, but here is a demo for you to play around with:

https://regex101.com/r/qF7bP6/1

**Errors:**

You have a couple of items that I can tell right away are going to throw off your match.

I can see that you are checking for `RewriteRules` instead of `RewriteRule`.

Additionally, you are matching the RewriteRule Flags in square braces like this `[NC,NE,L,R]`.  Square braces are special characters in regular expressions, so you're actually attempting to matching an optional single character which must be either a comma or one of the following letters: `N`, `C`, `E`, `L` or `R`.

Finally, you are requiring a space after the URL, even if there is no RewriteRule flag present.  There may be more, but those are the ones that jumped out at me.